# Unity 2D c# scripting, Spawnobject at mouseposition when down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to C#(basically first time using, having to script for this project), I'm trying to teleport (from off screen to on) an object in my game(i'm using a cube for a simple object, in which I will use inkscape to create a 'better' object in its place when it works)will add cube2 later, just focusing on getting this working.

The aim is to teleport an object to where to my 'Bumber' prefab (the floor), based upon the player clicking a position on the 'Bumber' and spawn where the mouse position was on that 'Bumber' and if not on the 'Bumber' don't spawn at all(haven't go to bumber check yet), which will trigger an event, causing the player to lose.

When I was playing the game before, when I clicked, the cube would only despawn and then throw an error at me and not spawn in at the cursors position

I have my 'cube' prefab (dragged from hierarchy into Resources folder, which has the spawn script component). When I go back into unity, I get the error:

(32, 37) the name 'cube' doesn't exist in current context

(32,25) The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(UnityEngine.Object, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Quaternion)' has some invalid arguments

(32, 25) Argument `#1' cannot convert`object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Object'

I've tried for hours to fix this script, looking at unity database and to no avail.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

public int trapCount;

void Start ()
{
    trapCount = 0;
    GameObject cube =(GameObject)Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("cube"));
}


void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {

        Spawner ();
        trapCount++;
    }
}

void Spawner()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    if(trapCount == 0)
    {
        Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);     //getting error here, I don't care about rotation value, don't want to rotate at all, but doesn't like it, if it doesn't have anything there.
    }

    else if (trapCount >= 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trap limit reached!");
    }
}
```

}

C# please, also, if you could, explain what you're doing, thank you kindly!

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Comment: Thx for the tag correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always (well, almost always) believe what the error messages tell you.

> (32, 37) the name 'cube' doesn't exist in current context

You get this for the line

```
Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

At that point there is no `cube` anywhere within the scope of the method. You have your

```
GameObject cube =(GameObject)Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("cube"));
```

in your `Start()` method, but it only exist within that method. It's not a member of the class for example. Making it a member would solve that problem.

And that is more than likely also the cause of the subsequent errors. If it doesn't know what a cube is, it has no idea what to do with it as an argument of `Instantiate()`.

If you're entirely new to C# the biggest favour you could do yourself is to pick up a good book. Unity will allow you to get pretty far by hacking away at it, but there will be a point where there's simply no substitute for learning the language. It will help you tremendously.

Good luck.